# Flex4 datagrid resfresh error

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, flex4.5

I have a problem when I refresh my datagrid with new XMLListCollection.

```
public function showMyData(result:XML):void
    {                   
        var data:XMLListCollection = new XMLListCollection(result.elements(DefData.EED_LIST_PATH));

        // Refresh all the EED list
        this.eed.dataProvider = new XMLListCollection(data.source);

    }
```

My XMLListCollection is good. But my datagrid shows only (in this case) 1 element. If I reduce, then maximise the navigator windows, all elements are showing correctly.

Comment: I have a similar problem with mx:Tree + XMLListCollection. Seems to be a bug in Flex, obviously. I’m not sure yet how to get around it.